# Flask: Clear session from admin prospective

Tags: flask, flask-session

In my flask app, logout can clear the session.

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

But logout is called only when user click logout on my website.

I am implementing a functionality where i can block a mysterious user. So, i need to force logout the user without his consent. My logic would also work if i can clear his session. Please guide.

Note: someone suggested to change app.secret_key. But that would clear session for all users and not a particular user only.

Answer (score 1):

So you have to check out if user is banned or not before each request!

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    user = findUser()
    if user.isBanned():
        return redirect(url_for('logout'))
```

Something like this would work,

Ofc you have to implant `findUser` and `isBanned`, findUser should return a `User` object, and `isBanned` should return `True` or `False`

Comment: isBanned would be fetched from database. blocked user may be 1 out of 1000. But in this approach, i have to make db request call for all users on every operation. I am looking for a way so that i can clear session for a particular user without making so many extra calls for each user.

Comment: Yeah, this is the only method without hardcoding, u can use a key-pair-value database, like redis, then check inside it which user should get kicked out instead of querying to main database